# Change in behaviour with Sheets permissions and getvalue?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a few Google Sheets supported by google apps scripts, and the behaviour of the script has changed overnight.

After a lot troubleshooting the problem with the script seems to be the use of range.getValue() - when the range is on another sheet to the one active. The error that users get is a they don't have permissions to edit the sheet. Which is strange because they are not trying to edit the cell they are taking the value from, they **do** have permissions to edit that cell anyway, and before today  I have never had a permissions error with .getValue() even when said cell is protected.

I myself am able to use the script fine as I have full permissions on the sheet, but I've gone through the script line by line on other accounts and confirmed that all steps can be done "manually" on the other accounts.

I also got permissions error with .clear({contents: only}), I was able solve this by replacing it with the identical .clearContent().

Is this a glitch or has Google changed something fundamental with the way GAS interacts with Google Sheets? If the latter are these changes documented anywhere?

Edit as someone asked for more details:

I can't really give a copy of the spreadsheet as it contains company information, but I can provide some of the code:

```
function function() {
....
  interface.getRange('G7').clearContent()
  interface.getRange('A6').clearContent()
  Utilities.sleep(5000)


  var a =arng.getValue()
  var b =brng.getValue()
 var c =crng.getValue() 
 var d = drng.getValue()
}

}
```

Now the Script Editor gives me a permissions error at the getValue lines, but I've just remembered there is a glitch with the new script editor where it sometimes tells you the wrong line number for where an error occurs so now thinking about it further I think it's happening at the clearContent() lines. I've checked and triple checked that users with standard permissions on the sheet have access to edit cells A6 and G7, however most of the rest of the sheet is protected. The way I did it was to protect the whole sheet "except certain cells", where A6 and G7 are cells that can be edited by general users.

Now, based on this what I think is happening is for some reason GAS isn't recognising that these cells can be edited even though they can. When I lift the restrictions the script works as intended. As mentioned before the script worked as intended for all users as recently as yesterday.

Though this doesn't fully explain things as I started a new script with the clearContent() lines copy and pasted and it worked there fine.

I've not been able to troubleshoot yet but I've been getting reports of similar errors in other spreadsheets.

Comment: Can you provide more information about your situation? Code, copy of the spreadsheet, steps to reproduce, etc.

Comment: I've edited the main body with further info

Comment: Is there a way to reproduce this? Does it happen only in a specific spreadsheet, you've been able to reproduce in several spreadsheets?